# How Do I Create a Relationship Between Two Users in Flask SQL alchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Please am working on a Chat application using flask.. But I'm having a little issue . I want to be able to create a relationship between two users in my flak SQLite..

And I want the messages of only those two users to show when ever I click their link..

For example, if a current user wants to chat up another user on that website, how will their relationship work.. Please someone should explain to me

Comment: first of You should provide what You have tried, a [mre]. Second, I don't think that there is a need for a relationship, just simply allow only those two people to enter the chatroom by using their id's, so basically if the id is this and id is this then return the correct template, but the "issue" is that You have no way of updating the chat in real time, at least not without some javascript I think. like yes You can manage this with post requests and stuff but using javascript for better looks and auto updating stuff will have to be done if You want that kind of hting

Comment: Sorry, But, how do I create a Notification to the other user that a user has sent a Message to him

Comment: without reloading the page? You need javascript, otherwise just every time there is a request for that chat query the database that contains all the messages and You could have a field in the database that tracks the number of total messages and a number of current messages so if the total messages is bigger than current (current is the ones that have been loaded, so basically the total amount of messages from the previous request), then render a template with the notification. However for sth like this You should use javascript for user convenience

Comment: Sorry, you made mention that i should allow two users to enter a chat room and then get their IDs.., How do I create that chat room and at the same time get the users Id... please answer me..

Comment: so You have a route and in the function first thing You do is check the user id and if it is allowed to continue then continue, otherwise redirect or abort, one way is to just make a link that consists of gibberish random characters so basically only the people that know the link can enter, that way You don't even need to check, because if it is a long enough string of random characters, guessing them is quite a smallllll chance

Comment: the thing is that this is no much of how to code it, You have to get the logic, ok? so like figure out how that should happen logically without thinking how to code it, then code it